# sql using count with group by and having

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble when it comes to writing queries that involve aggregate functions (such as Count and also when using Having). I have two tables of People (id and name) and Books (bookid, author_id, title) (here author_id is a foreign key to People id). 
I currently have a query that returns to me all the People who have written a book (not all the people have written a book).

```
SELECT People.name, 
       Books.title 
FROM People, 
     Books 
WHERE Books.author_id = People.id;
```

Now I am trying to find only People who have written more than 2 books and have it select the same info (people.name and books.title), but I am confused as to how I would go about this. I have been trying to use a HAVING count(People.name) > 1 but the selection I get is definitely not correct.

Sort of new to using sql especially when it comes to putting these extra parameters on my queries and was just wondering if anyone could help me out. I have not really seen any examples of queries with these conditions.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to join your table this way:

```
SELECT People.name, Books.title
FROM People INNER JOIN Books ON Books.author_id = People.id;
```

and you can add your HAVING clause as this:

```
SELECT Books.author_id
FROM Books
GROUP BY Books.author_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```

then to select all the info you need you could use this:

```
SELECT People.name, Books.title
FROM People INNER JOIN Books ON Books.author_id = People.id
WHERE People.ID IN (
  SELECT Books.author_id
  FROM Books
  GROUP BY Books.author_id
  HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT People.name, 
       Books.title 
FROM People, 
     Books 
WHERE Books.author_id = People.id 
  and exists (select 1 
              from (
                 SELECT People.name name 
                 FROM People, 
                      Books 
                 WHERE Books.author_id = People.id 
                 group by Pepole.name 
                 having count(People.name)>1
              ) temp 
              where temp.name = People.name)
```